# Windows Task Scheduler wont start task because it thinks previous version is still running

Tags: windows, powershell

I have an occasional problem (maybe twice a month) were windows task scheduler won't start a new task because it thinks the old version is still running.

The task is a powershell script, it runs all day, every day. The task scheduler starts the script at 5 past midnight every day (UTC), and then the scripts exits itself everyday at 23:55 (UTC). The script does the following actions.

- logs its own startup in a database
- spends all day reading records from a remote server.
- logs its own shutdown at 23:55 every night and exits with 'exit 0'

Task scheduler runs the script with the -NoExit option, so the powershell console remains open on the screen even after the task has exited (allowing a visual check of any output generated)

This all works fine 95% of the time, however, occasionally when the task scheduler attempts to start the new task at 00:05 I see the message 'Launch request ignored, instance already running' in the history. But when I check the log records from the powershell script I see that it started and finished at it's normal time, and I can double check this against the console.

Curiously, on these occasions the task scheduler history indicates that the blocking task finished at about 8am - a time which always corresponds to when I logged on that day.

Any suggestions on what's going wrong and how to sure it? I've already tried tweaking some of the task settings "if the task is already running then the following rule applies - stop the existing instance" but because the fault is intermittent, it's very hard to pin down.

Update - following further testing.
I've tried creating 100s of similar tasks and running them with similar conditions. So far I've reached two conclusions, firstly everything seems to work OK if I remove the -NoExit option. It's almost as if the scheduler has trouble differentiating between the command window, and the PowerShell script itself.

Secondly, everything seems to work ok if increase the gap between the previous schedule dying and the new one starting from about 15 minutes to half an hour or longer. It's as if the task scheduler takes time to work out that the old task has stopped.

Comment: What are the defined trigger(s) for this task?  Is "Run only when user is logged on" selected in security options (Task Properties > General tab)?  Is "Stop task if it runs longer than X" enabled in the trigger (Task Properties > Triggers tab > Edit..)?  Is "Stop the task if it runs longer than X" enabled for the task (Task Properties > Settings tab)?  Does this issue occur around daily savings time changes?